# how to concatenate a file with multiple header into one

Tags: text-processing

Can you suggest me how I can combine.

a.fasta with 10000 sequences having headers 1, 2, 3, .... 10000  .......................into just  one header e.g

```
>1
AAATTTTGGGGCCC
>2
ACCCCGGGTTT
..........
>10000
ATGCCCCCCCCCC
```

Output:

```
>1
AAATTTTGGGGCCCACCCCGGGTTTATGCCCCCCCCCC
```

Comment: Are blank lines in your input?

Comment: I removed the blank lines since your file probably doesn't have them. Please roll back my edit if I was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '
    /^>/ { 
        # print the first header
        if (c++ == 0) {print; print ""} 
        next
    } 
    /^$/ {next} 
    {printf "%s", $0} 
    END {print ""}
' a.fasta > b.fasta
```

contents of b.fasta

```
>1

AAATTTTGGGGCCCACCCCGGGTTT..........ATGCCCCCCCCCC
```

Comment: sorry i am a newbie in this field so do i need to create a file and copy this script and then run or what

Comment: copy the command and paste into a shell prompt.

Comment: i am surprised the commands worked fine but it changes the format of file to txt

Comment: If there should not be the blank line after the header, remove `; print ""` from the `if (c++ ...` line. If that's not what you mean, then I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to just print the 1st line and then all the other lines of the file that don't contain i) any spaces character (they have no business being in fasta files) and ii) a fasta header line (`>`):

```
head -n 1 file.fa > newfile.fa; grep -P '^[^> ]+$' >>  newfile.fa
```

The `head` prints the 1st line, and the grep regular expression looks for all lines that contain only non-`>` and non-space characters (`[^> ]`) from the beginning (`^`) to the end (`$`) of the line.

However, this will result in a file like this:

```
>1
AAATTTTGGGGCCC
ACCCCGGGTTT
ATGCCCCCCCCCC
```

To get the entire sequence on the same line, use this instead:

```
head -n 1 file.fa > newfile.fa; grep -P '^[^> ]+$' | tr -d '\n'>>  newfile.fa;
```

You can then add an extra newline to the end of the file with

```
echo "" >> newfile.fa
```

---

However, if you will be working with such files, I suggest you save these two scripts in a file in your $PATH (`$HOME/bin` for example) and make them executable (`chmod a+x $HOME/bin/scriptname`):

#### FastaToTbl

This script takes a fasta file and changes it to tbl format (the fasta header, a tab and then the sequence, all on one line):

```
#! /bin/sh
gawk '{
        if (substr($1,1,1)==">")
        if (NR>1)
                    printf "\n%s\t", substr($0,2,length($0)-1)
        else 
            printf "%s\t", substr($0,2,length($0)-1)
        else 
                printf "%s", $0
}END{printf "\n"}'  "$@"
```

#### TblToFasta

This does the inverse, it takes a file in tbl format and converts it to a correct fasta file (`>` header and 60 characters per line):

```
#! /bin/sh

gawk '{
  sequence=$NF

  ls = length(sequence)
  is = 1
  fld  = 1

# if (fld == 1){printf ">"}
  
  while (fld < NF)
  {
     if (fld == 1){printf ">"}
     printf "%s " , $fld
    
     if (fld == NF-1)
      {
        printf "\n"
      }
      fld = fld+1
  }
  
  while (is <= ls)
  {
    printf "%s\n", substr(sequence,is,60)
    is=is+60
  }
}' "$@"
```

Now, if you had had these scripts available, you could have done what you asked for by simply running:

```
$ head -n 1 file.fa; FastaToTbl file.fa | awk -F"\t" '{print $2}'
>1
AAATTTTGGGGCCC
ACCCCGGGTTT..........
ATGCCCCCCCCCC
```

Or, to get a correct fasta file:

```
 $ head -n 1 file.fa > newfile; FastaToTbl file.fa | 
    awk -F"\t" '{printf "%s", $2}' | TblToFasta >> newfile
```

Which produces:

```
>1
AAATTTTGGGGCCCACCCCGGGTTT..........ATGCCCCCCCCCC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{ echo '>1'; tr -dc '[:alpha:]'; } <infile >outfile
```

You dont need to get the first line out of the file - just `echo` a header. And if you delete everything but alphabetic characters then you just automatically get what you want.

Comment: Thanks @Braiam - it really wasnt a low-quality post though - it just didnt need a lot of explaining. still i did it.